# evaluating $\int_0^{k!}e^{i\frac{t^k}{k!}} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

How to evaluate the following integral?$$
\int_0^{k!}e^{i\frac{x^k}{k!}} dx
$$ Here $k$ can be any positive integer. When $k=2$, I can square it and use polar coordinates. But I've no idea about the general $k$.

Comment: You can evaluate the integral in terms of the incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: I've provided the answer in terms of the Lower Incomplete Gamma function.  It isn't pretty.

Comment: I hope that my answer was of use to you.  I really do want to help, so, please let me know if there is any way that I can improve my answer.  I just want it to be the best possible answer for you.

Comment: @Dr.MV Sorry for my late reply and thank you for your answer. I got this question from an exercise in a textbook and it seems to me the integral should depend linearly on $k$.

Comment: Why do you believe that the dependence should be linear on $k$?

Comment: @Dr.MV The exercise says so. You see that the upper limit of the integral and the coefficient of $x^k$ match. I suspect that there should be some nice cancellation going on.

Comment: $\frac{(k!)^k}{k!} = (k!)^{k-1}$.  I'm not sure it is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=-i\frac{x^k}{k!}\Rightarrow x=(ik!)^{\frac{1}{k}} t^{\frac{1}{k}}$.  Then, we have

$$dt=-i\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}dx$$
$$x=(ik!t)^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
$$I=\int_0^{k!} e^{i\frac{x^k}{k!}}dx=C_k\int_0^{-i(k!)^{k-1}} t^{\frac1k-1}e^{-t}dt$$
where $C_k=-(i)^{\frac{1}{k}}\frac{(k!)^{\frac1k}}{k}$.  Now, noting that the lower Incomplete Gamma function $\gamma (s,x)$is given by
$$\gamma (s,x)=\int_0^x t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$then $I$ is given by
$$I=C_k \gamma \left(\frac{1}{k},-i(k!)^{k-1}\right)$$